# Ruby regular expression for number that should respect some rules per number groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to build an expression (num) but the construction should respect some rules
I need to check a number (13digits) that is buld from some groups
I succeed to build one (see below)  but I need to add some rules

[1-9]{1}.?[0-9]{2}.?[0-9]{2}.?[0-9]{2}.?[0-9]{2}.?[0-9]{3}.?[0-9][1]{0,20}

Rules are the following :

Group 3 => [0-9]{2} should be only like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (months)

Group 4 => [0-9]{2} should be only like  1,2, … 31 (days)

Group 5 => [0-9]{2} should be only like 1,2,3, ….. 53

How can I define these rules ?

thank you

Comment: Can you post a sample input string?

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

1. Break up the values by splitting on the `.`
2. Use code to validate the values after converting to integers

Not all problems are regex's forte: implementing (relatively) complex business rules is one of those things. This is not regex's forte: regex here would be harder to modify, understand, and debug.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I need to identify into a number some rules : I have a number with 6 digit that represent the date : first 2 digits represent the last two digits of the year (18 from 2018), next two represent the month (01,02,....12) and the last two the day (1,2, … 31). And using this rules I can validate if a number respect the rules. Ex. 120331 => ok, 121445 does not (month = 14 and day 45)